# Disconnect with SoftAP

Tags: esp8266, arduino-esp8266

I have an problem with the SoftAP of ESP8266-Arduino.

If ACCESS_POINT is false everything works fine.
But if ACCESS_POINT is true: It works. But after a few seconds of data transmissions the AP is gone. The only way to reconnect is to restart the ESP8266.

I need the AP mode for using mobile with the smartphone.

I've already cleared the memory of the ESP8266 complete. But it doesn't help...

```
#define PIN_NEOPIXEL 2
#define PIN_LED_SWITCH 0

#define NUMPIXELS 60

#define ACCESS_POINT true

Adafruit_NeoPixel pixels = Adafruit_NeoPixel(NUMPIXELS, PIN_NEOPIXEL, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);

ESP8266WebServer server(80);
WebSocketsServer webSocket(81);

void webSocketEvent(uint8_t num, WStype_t type, uint8_t * payload, size_t lenght) {
    switch (type) {
        case WStype_BIN:
            //Serial.printf("[%u] get Text: %s  %u\n", num, payload, lenght);
            if (payload[0] == '#') {
                if(lenght == 1 + NUMPIXELS * 3) {
                    for(int i=0;i<NUMPIXELS;i++){
                        int r = payload[1 + i * 3];
                        int g = payload[1 + i * 3 + 1];
                        int b = payload[1 + i * 3 + 2];

                        pixels.setPixelColor(i, pixels.Color(r,g,b));
                    }

                    pixels.show();
                }
            }
            if (payload[0] == '!') { //LED ein/aus
                if (payload[1] == '1') {
                    digitalWrite(PIN_LED_SWITCH, false);
                    pinMode(PIN_LED_SWITCH, OUTPUT);
                } else {
                    pinMode(PIN_LED_SWITCH, INPUT_PULLUP);
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}


void setup() {
    pixels.begin();

    Serial.begin(115200);

    WiFi.mode(WIFI_OFF);
    if(!ACCESS_POINT) {
        WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
        WiFi.begin("SSID", "...key...");

        while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
            delay(1000);
        }

        Serial.print("IP address:\t");
        Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
    } else {
        WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP);
        IPAddress apIP(192, 168, 4, 1);
        IPAddress netMsk(255, 255, 255, 0);
        WiFi.softAPConfig(apIP, apIP, netMsk);
        WiFi.softAP("Pixelstick");
        while (WiFi.softAPgetStationNum() < 1) {
            delay(1000);
        }
    }


    server.on("/", []() {
        server.send(200, "text/html", INDEX_HTML);
    });
    server.begin();

    webSocket.begin();
    webSocket.onEvent(webSocketEvent);
}

void loop() {
    webSocket.loop();
    server.handleClient();
    yield();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not give any versions of SW or HW:

The following works stable on a NodeMCU v0.9 and v1.0 (ESP8266-12E)

IDE -> Arduino IDE 1.85 with ESP Package version 2.42 (worked also with 2.41)

Version of the package can be checked here 
C:\Users[YOURUSERNAME]\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2

For these environments do the following

```
void loop() {
    webSocket.loop();
    server.handleClient();
 //   yield(); ==> delete this line
}
```

yield() leads to unpredictable behavior with the esp8266 libs - in older versions this was used as a workaround to some bugs but was never a satisfying solution